# Using a Flat Catalog

Tags: magento2

Can anyone explain to me the reason why Magento no longer recommend the use of [catalog flat table](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html). As per the official documentation, it's degrading the performance because of the slow/long SQL queries, but, why now? not in M1. Please give me any logical reason

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this is due to the introduction of [Elasticsearch](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/configuration/catalog/catalog.html#elasticsearch) support to Magento open source 2.3+. Indexing flat catalog has always been slow, the introduction of Elasticsearch simply introduced a more efficient alternative.

Comment: Hello @Andrew Kett, I get all attribute selected in the array while I activate Use Flat Catalog Product. If it's No then only few attribute are selected in my collection. Can  you please explain why ? I want All product attribute selected in my custom collection.